# Angular View fails to load from template, when rendered via PhantomJS

Tags: angularjs, phantomjs

I have an Angular application that is leveraging template caching (part of our Gulp build process). The application runs fine, the cached views load... Except when rendered through PhantomJS (or Google's Pagespeed or Fetch as Google for that matter).

After much investigation, I found that routing is throwing this error:

```
Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: /static/app/public/views/about.html (HTTP status: undefined undefined)
```

I am assuming the HTTP status of undefined is related to the fact that no round trip is occurring... but I can't find any information on why this would fail, and especially why only when using the above mentioned tools.

To summarize:

- App runs fine on Chrome, IE, Firefox, Opera
- The cached template .js file contains the necessary path and html content
- The path fails to resolve when loading through PhantomJS, Speedtest renderer, or Google's "Fetch as Google" tools
- I have reviewed the Angular documentation on why this error is thrown, but it still doesn't make sense, the template has been populated (as the file template .js has been loaded)

**Edit**

I added the following line for debugging:

```js
    var about = $templateCache.get('/static/app/public/views/about.html');
    console.log('about', about);
```

... and I see the proper output in the console log, even with PhantomJS.

Comment: do you still have the problem, or its solved?

Comment: Still a problem... you responded within a few minutes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I was ignoring another error message:

```
Error: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'newUrl.startsWith(target)')
```

... happening due to PhantomJS's ES5. I didn't think the two issues were related, but after providing a polyfill for String.prototype.startsWith, the issue went away.